# How to make an rest endpoint public in Hasura (Requires no authentication)?

Tags: rest, graphql, hasura

Is there a way to make a rest endpoint public in Hasura?

Say I have restaurants table and I created a rest endpoint for that,
say `http://localhost:8080/api/rest/restaurants/:id`
How can I make this endpoint public?

I tried creating a new role on the table and gave it select permissions without any checks but I don't know how to set the role using rest nor there's a mention of that in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Exposing your REST endpoint in Hasura works the same as a GraphQL endpoint. For public access, you can configure an unauthorised role and you're good to go. You can check out our docs [here](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/auth/authentication/unauthenticated-access.html) to see how you can set up the unauthorised access.

Comment: This Hasura deep-dive [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vy4iXukXc8Y) walks through this step-by-step.